# StreamReader C#

Tags: c#, streamreader, text-files

While reading a text file(which contains the location of a file to be exported to a database) using the streamReader function in C#, how can I add a confirmation message to the code that will be displayed in the command prompt window(console application) so that I know the file got read and was exported?

```
public class Script
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Prepare the type that will handle all of the exporting needs
        FileExporter exporter = new FileExporter();

        try
        {
            //create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            //The using statemen also closes the StreamReader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("ScriptFile.txt"))
            {
                string filePath;
                //read and display lines from the file until the end of
                //the file is reached.
                while ((filePath = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // Throw error if file does not exists to terminate the process.
                    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        string msg = string.Format("File not found at {0}.", filePath);
                        throw new FileNotFoundException(msg);
                    }

                    // Set the name of the export to be the name of the file.
                    string exportName = new FileInfo(filePath).Name;

                    // Export image as an SHP file if the extension matches.
                    if (filePath.Contains(".shp"))
                    {
                        exporter.processSHP(filePath, exportName, "");
                        //need confirmation that exporter.processSHP occured <<<-----***
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string fileExtension = filePath.Split('.')[filePath.Split('.').Length - 1];

                        exporter.processIMG(filePath, exportName, "", fileExtension); 
                        //need confirmation that exporter.processIMG occured <<<-----***
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format("Process terminated. An error has occurred: {0}", e.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you post a sample code of what you´re doing? I don´t quite understand... wouldn´t a Console.WriteLine command do it?

Comment: The question as phrased has nothing to do with the topic, and only asks how to write to the concole window. Please clarify.

Answer (score 9):

Add this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Done reading & Exporting");
```

above

```
}
catch (Exception e)
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the Console.ReadKey() in case you want to actually see it up there

Answer (score 0):

use flush and then close on your writer object.

then write done to console.

Comment: Actually, Close should be enough. But you should consider an using(...){...}

Answer (score 0):

After you read the file to the end and look for your match (assuming you have something like a boolean value to let you know the export happened and a match was found) you can check the EndOfStream property in the streamreader and output the message. Or you can just check your match value to see if it returned true.